# How to fetch the record whose column value is less than previous dates in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table which look like

```
id| value     |date
1 | 11        |2016-10-01 01:00:00
2 | 12        |2016-10-02 01:00:00
3 | 13        |2016-10-03 01:00:00
4 | 2         |2016-10-04 01:00:00
5 | 1         |2016-10-05 01:00:00
6 | 14        |2016-10-06 01:00:00
```

here i need to retrieve the output be like this

```
id| value     |date
4 | 2         |2016-10-04 01:00:00
5 | 1         |2016-10-05 01:00:00
```

whose value lesser than previous dates '2016-10-03 01:00:00'

Comment: he is not quering about '2016-10-03' only, he want to have a list of data comparing if the value of current line is less than the value of the previous date value!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using subquery [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/928cc6/1)

```
/*create the table*/
CREATE TABLE datas(
    ID INT(11) PRIMARY KEY,
    vals INT(11) NULL,
    dates DATETIME NULL
);
/*insert the datas*/
INSERT INTO datas VALUES(1,'11','2016-10-01 01:00:00');
INSERT INTO datas VALUES(2,'12','2016-10-02 01:00:00');
INSERT INTO datas VALUES(3,'13','2016-10-03 01:00:00');
INSERT INTO datas VALUES(4,'2','2016-10-04 01:00:00');
INSERT INTO datas VALUES(5, '1','2016-10-05 01:00:00');
INSERT INTO datas VALUES(6,'14','2016-10-06 01:00:00');
/*the query*/
SELECT results.* FROM datas AS results
WHERE
results.`vals` < ( 
    SELECT prevs.`vals` 
    FROM datas AS prevs 
    WHERE prevs.`dates` < results.`dates` 
    ORDER BY prevs.`dates` DESC 
    LIMIT 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other possible solutions (using the table declares from @Aroniaina ).

Firstly, using a user variable to get all the records on order and carry over the value from the previous row to compare against

```
SELECT id, vals, dates 
FROM
(
    SELECT sub1.*,
            @prev_val AS prev_val,
            @prev_val:=vals
    FROM
    (SELECT @prev_val:=0) sub0
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, vals, dates 
        FROM datas
        ORDER BY dates 
    ) sub1
) sub2
WHERE prev_val > vals
```

Or doing a JOIN, where the date is smaller, and using GROUP_CONCAT / SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the latest previous value, so it can be compared in the HAVING clause.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM datas a
INNER JOIN datas b
ON a.dates > b.dates
GROUP BY a.id, a.vals, a.dates 
HAVING a.vals < SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(b.vals ORDER BY b.dates DESC), ',', 1)
```